# RFCOMM multiple connections for channel

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez, rfcomm

I am implementing Bluetooth server, which supports multiple clients. I am using RFCOMM protocol. Is it possible to connect many clients for the same RFCOMM channel?

**Server code for(C++):**

```
int client;
std::list<boost::thread *> pool;
boost::thread *t;
struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
int s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
fflush(stdout);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));
fflush(stdout);
listen(s, 1);
while(1){
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &rem_addr, &opt);
    cout << "Accepted " << endl;
    t = new boost::thread(&read_data,client, this);
    pool.push_back(t);
    t->join();
}
```

`read_data` is processing function for connection

**Clients connects via this code(Java/Android):**

```
        ...
        BluetoothDevice mmDevice = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice(serverAddress);
        String data;
        Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 1);
        ...
```

Client from first device sucessfully connected and send/receive data from server. Client from second device succesfully connected to server. I can see this message in android log:

```
D/BluetoothEventLoop(  194): Device property changed: 00:15:83:3D:0A:57 property: Connected value: true
```

**BUT** no second "Accepted" message from server and no data received for second client after connection.

Comment: You have a thread join in your server loop. Have you checked whether the "read_data" thread actually completes and exits?

Comment: Thank you, Alan! Stupid me, missed that, cause of wrong understanding of join.